# Get image in JS from HTML src and replace it after CSS styling

Tags: javascript

How can i get the image or images from HTML and to replace in JS element.style.backgroundImage = "url('image')"? The example below work fine!

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.image-container');

img.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541443131876-44b03de101c5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80";
img.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
img.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
img.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";

img.src = img;
```

```css
.image-container {
  width: 425px;
  height: 575px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
</div>
```

But i want to add img src and to get every image in JS

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.img').src;

img.style.backgroundImage = "url('img')";
img.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
img.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
img.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";

img.src = img;
```

```css
.image-container img {
  width: 425px;
  height: 575px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">  
  <img class="img"src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541443131876-44b03de101c5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
</div>
```

That it doesn't work, how can i fix it to work for every image in HTML to show with CSS properly changes like first example.

Comment: This `document.querySelector('.img').src` gives the the `img url` and not the `img` element itself. If you want the actual `img` element then use this `document.querySelector('.img')`

Comment: I want the image url, not the image to set in img.style.backgroundImage = "url('x')"

Comment: But you can't do `img.style.backgroundImage = "url('x')" `  if `img` is just `src`

Comment: It doesn't work with .img, please try it. I want to get from src the url and to put in `style.backgroundImage = "url('there')";` To show the image not like `src="https://image.jpg"` in the HTML code, but like inline style e.g. `style="background-image: image.jpg; etc ..."`

Comment: This `document.querySelector('.img').src`  gives you the url value of the `src`, but you saved it in a variable `img` and you're trying to `img.style.backgroundImage` which isn't valid. Question is which element do you want to do this `.style.backgroundImage =` on?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Select all images
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image-container img');

Array.from(images).forEach(img => {

img.style.backgroundImage = "url('img')";
img.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
img.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
img.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";

// Set url to whatever you want
img.src = url;
})
```

Comment: No need for `Array.from(images)`, just `images.forEach()` should do

Comment: Yes, i used to use that since forEach on NodeList in the past was not possible in all browsers.

Comment: @munleashed well, today it's not a concern any more. NodeList.ForEach() is available in all modern browsers. It's a defacto standard way to tackle *eaching* of Elements list

Comment: It doesn't work that elements style     background-image: url(img);   background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-size: cover;  background-position: center center; I need to put the image with JS like to add the image with CSS background-image: url('image') no-repeat center center / cover; to work that attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This code will loop through all images in image-containers and set the parent div to have the image src then remove the image from the dom.

I moved the repeating CSS background styles to the CSS class instead.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image-container img');

images.forEach(function(img) {
  img.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  img.remove();
})
```

```css
.image-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-Size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541443131876-44b03de101c5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"></div>
<div class="image-container"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/200/FF33AA"></div>
```